# Mouse event return bad coordinates?

Tags: c#, winforms

in my app i am using mouse down and mouse up event to get coords of pointer, using them i am drawing a rectangle. But i have a problem, right-down corner is moved about 5px up and 5 px left from the place i have drop the mouse up event.
I have no more ideas why doesnt it work.

Here is the Code i am using.

```
private void sourceBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sourceBox.Image != null && enableMR)
        {
            X1 = e.X;
            Y1 = e.Y;
        }
    }
private void sourceBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (sourceBox.Image != null && enableMR)
        {
            SampleRbutton.Enabled = true;
            Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(sourceBox.Image);
            float scalex = (float)temp.Width / sourceBox.Width;
            float scaley = (float)temp.Height / sourceBox.Height;
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(temp);
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red,5f);
            actselectionF = new RectangleF(Math.Min(X1, e.X) * scalex, Math.Min(Y1, e.Y) * scaley, Math.Abs((e.X - X1) * scalex), Math.Abs((e.Y - Y1) * scaley));
            sampleBox.Image = copyselection(actselectionF, temp);
            g.DrawRectangle(p, Math.Min(X1, e.X) * scalex, Math.Min(Y1, e.Y) * scaley, Math.Abs((e.X - X1) * scalex), Math.Abs((e.Y - Y1) * scaley));            
            sourceBox.Image = temp;
            c.Flush();
            o.State = (Bitmap)sampleBox.Image;
            c.PushCurrentState(o.CreateMemento());
            enableMR = false;
            SampleRbutton.Checked = true;
            hsaitextBox.Text = sampleBox.Image.Height.ToString();
            wsaitextBox.Text = sampleBox.Image.Width.ToString();
            g.Dispose();
            p.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Here you have the problem i am talking about.

Comment: what is your pointer shape in windows?

Comment: Your pointer is contained within a rectangle, the origin of which is likely vertically and horizontally centered. If you do not want to drop at the top-left of your pointer you may need to account for that.

Comment: Your `Pen` object is defined as `Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 5f);`. Since your pen is 5 pixels wide, you need to subtract that from the cursor position to get your actual position.

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was Fixed 3D border style of picture box in which i was taking coordinates. Thanks mates :)